# Having trouble satisfying the maxheap property using a list

Tags: python, list, function, data-structures, heap

I am creating a MaxHeap class and I have to do it using a list. I am having trouble inserting an element into the heap in the correct order to satisfying the maxheap requirement. I am not allowed to add anything to the constructor. What should I do?

```
class MaxHeap:  

    def __init__(self):
        self.Heap=[]

    def parent(self, pos): 
        return pos//2


    def leftChild(self, pos): 
        return 2 * pos 


    def rightChild(self, pos): 
        return (2 * pos) + 1

    def insert(self, element):
        self.Heap.append(element)
        child = len(self.Heap) - 1

        while child > 0:
            parent = self.parent(child)
            if self.Heap[parent] >= self.Heap[child]:
                return

            self.Heap[child], self.Heap[parent] = self.Heap[parent], self.Heap[child]
            child = parent
```

### What my code does (left) vs what is expected (right) (separated by |)

x = MaxHeap()

**x.insert(10)**

- [10] | [10]

**x.insert(5)**

- [10,5] | [10,5]

**x.insert(14)**

- [14,10,5] | [14,5,10]  **-> first place things start going wrong**

**x.insert(9)**

- [14,10,5,9]   | [14,9,10,5]  **my code is wrong again and for the rest as well**

**x.insert(2)**

- [14,10,5,9,2]   | [14,9,10,5,2]

**x.insert(11)**

- [14,11,10,9,2,5]  |  [14,9,11,5,2,10]

**x.insert(6)**

- [14,11,10,9,2,5,6]  | [14,9,11,5,2,10,6]

When inserting 14, it is initially the right child of 10. Then you swap 14 and 10, and the level traversal of the heap is the array representation, 14 is the parent, 5 the left child and 10 the right child etc.

When I originally add 14, it goes from [10,5] to [10,5,14]

Using [10,5,14], I compare 14 with it's parent, which would be 10. This does not satisfy the max heap property, so I have to switch 10 with 14, so that it becomes [14,5,10]

How would I do his?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python lists are indexed starting at 0, but the parent/child formulas you're using are for a heap rooted at 1.

For a heap rooted at 0:

```
leftChild(x) = x*2+1
rightChild(x) = x*2+2
parent(x) = (x-1)//2
```

Comment: Hi, how does that help me with my insert method?

Comment: Your insert would work properly if you were properly if your parent, leftChild, and rightChild functions were correct.

Comment: They do give the right result.  you can draw out a few levels of the tree and check:  0 / 1 2 / 3 4 5 6 / 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14